# Add version to a static file URL during load defined in the footer.blade file

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have a *footer.blade.php* file where I load all the JavaScript files.

Now I want to append the version to the URL dynamically.

Where globalFileVersion is defined in a separate file which I will not cache using [nginx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx).

I have tried a couple of ways to achieve this, but I failed every time.

#### First

```
<script src="../../assets/js/main/login.js?v=" + globalFileVersion></script>
```

#### Second

```
<script>import(`../../assets/js/main/generateInvoicePhp.js?version=${globalFileVersion}`)</script>
```

Comment: Is `globalFileVersion` a Javascript variable or a PHP variable?

Comment: its a javascript variable

Comment: Ok, so this likely isn't a PHP or Laravel question at all... we'll need more context about how you're trying to load scripts with this variable... can you provide more of the content from this Blade file?

Comment: I am trying one php way also where i have created versionFile.php in /resources/views/layout folder.. And in this file i have defined this variable "$globalFileVersion" and i am trying to access it in footer.blade.php using below code:
          
@include('/resources/views/layout.versionFile')

<p>Version: {{ $globalFileVersion }}</p>

Comment: If it's coming from PHP, this is simply a case of passing the value to your main view (the one that's loading `footer.blade.php`) file from your controller: `return view('main', ['globalFileVersion' => versionNumberGenerator()])` and using it appropriately in your view: `<script src=".../login.js?v={{ $globalFileVersion }}">`. But I suspect this isn't really what you need...

Answer (score 1):

On the surface, it appears that you're trying to version your assets to avoid browser/CDN caching, and you're intending to use quite a naive approach to that - a single variable value that is used for all assets.

A simple answer would tell you how to make the variable aspect render correctly so that your asset URLs all have this dynamic nature to them which will help with cache-busting when you need it to.

There are a few ways to 'skin this cat', but as you're dealing with Blade and likely running in the context of a Laravel application, what you *should* do is use Laravel's built-in support for [Asset Bundling](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite).

This is going to be a much better implementation than your naive one and has already taken care of so many considerations that you may not have thought through yet or encountered.

For example, while a query string parameter is fine for many caching systems, it can be ignored by some, so what you really want is a dynamically-generated file name.

Also, a single version key that is shared across all assets means that you will not be allowing your own systems or your users' systems to make the most effective use of their caching strategies, which will translate to unnecessary computation, transfer and storage costs across the stack.

Comment: Using some other library is not an option.

Comment: Agreed that the other two answers are AI-generated.  They were already in my "list" of likely-AI answers that I track (10,000+ answers and growing), but I simply don't have time to flag them all.  :-/  I just came across yours because I was searching for answers that mention ChatGPT ;-)

Comment: I cant use vite or any such library, i need to version my files by appending version at the end of the url while loading

Comment: *Why* can't you use Vite? It's an ideal candidate for solving the problem at hand

Comment: The [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) observation is meta information. Meta information [does not belong in answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011). It belongs in comments or not at all.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I disagree. There's nothing in your linked post that my observation should not be in my answer. It may very well be meta once these answers are no longer present as it will be contextually meaningless. But while they're still here, it's extremely relevant.